# Does an http post to a guest site count toward API limits?

Tags: api, httppost

I'm using a Twilio Studio Flow in conjunction with Salesforce. The flow makes an HTTP POST to a remote site set up on the org. (An apex class receives the data and fires a platform event, returning no data.)

The endpoint is `https://[domain].sandbox.my.salesforce-sites.com/twilio/services/apexrest/`.

The apex class handling the inbound data is this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/InboundTwilioService/*')
global without sharing class InboundTwilioService {
  //parses inbound data, fires platform event, no dml

}
```

Is this considered an api call to Salesforce? Will it affect our api call limits?

Comment: You should clean up this question. The best answer I have for now is "maybe?" What endpoint do you POST to?

Comment: Only Apex outbound callouts don't count towards API limits. Is twillio firing call to Salesforce org? If yes then it will get counted towards the org limit to which POST request is being fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is an inbound Apex REST service and is governed by this bit of the [APEX REST doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_intro.htm?q=rest)

> Governor Limits
>
> Calls to Apex REST classes count **against the organization's API governor limits**. All standard Apex governor limits apply to Apex REST classes. For example, the maximum request or response size is 6 MB for synchronous Apex or 12 MB for asynchronous Apex

So, yes, the call counts against your org's API call limits